# Size background list item dependent of item size

Tags: html, css, list, background-color, items

I have a unordered list as a menu.
All items have a background-color. What I want is that the width of the item does not fill the width of the list, and that the item (including the background-color) is aligned to the right in the list. I hope you understand and might have an answer.

HTML:

```
<ul class="menu">
<li><a class="menuitem">First</a></li>
<li><a class="menuitem">Secondwithlongertext</a></li>
<li><a class="menuitem">Thirdbitshorter</a></li>
</ul>
```

And CSS:

```
ul li a.menuitem{ 
background-color:#000;
color:#fff;
}
```

Comment: Just apply the background-color to the `A` elements instead of the `LI`, and use `text-align:right` on the `LI` or `UL` to have the links align to the right of the list … surprised you have to even ask for something as basic as this.

Comment: @CBroe Sorry for asking a question that might be basic to you. I couldn't figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per you requirement you have to wrap the text inside the `<span>`. Here is a working [Demo](http://jsbin.com/satoleda/1/).

Here is the HTML code.

```
<ul class="menu">
  <li><a class="menuitem"><span>First</span></a></li>
<li><a class="menuitem"><span>Second Item with long  text can come here</span></a></li>
<li><a class="menuitem"><span>Thirdbitshorter</span></a></li>
</ul>

ul { 
    background-color:gold;
    color:#fff;
}
ul li{
    background: #990000;
}
ul li a {
    text-align: right;
}
ul li span{ background:black;}
```

Comment: The `SPAN` elements are nonsense, you can give the background color to the `A` instead. And to have those align to the right, the text-align has to set on the `LI` or `UL` of course – aligning text within an element that is only as wide as the text demands is nonsense.

Answer (score 0):

```
ul { 
    background-color:#000;
    color:#fff;
    width: 100%;
}
ul li{
    background: #990000;
    width: 50%;
}
ul li a {
    text-align: right;
}
```

This should work for you if I understand what you're asking.  Sometimes I make the backgrounds different colors just to clearly be able to see what is going on.

Comment: Actually, I'm trying to make the li width depend on the content. So a long text should have a wider background than a short text. Ideas?

Comment: It will automatically adjust... Divs, links, and paragraphs aren't a predetermined width.